# else statement not working for the following php code

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this doctors schedule with dates and returning only those dates that are greater than today. But when there are dates that are previous to today,for which I am unable to return `No dates available`.

Here is my code:

```
$lists =  Gateway::Onlineschedule()->schedulelist($inputs['doctor_id']);
$today=date("d/M/Y");

if(count($lists) == 0)
{
    return 'No entry detected';

}
else
{
    foreach ($lists as $list) 
    {

        $api_procedure['Day'] = $list->day; 

        if($api_procedure['Day']>$today)
        {
            $listing[] = $api_procedure;
        }
        else
        {
            return 'No dates available';
        }
    }

    return json_encode($listing);

}
```

dd($lists) returns

```
Collection {#273
  #items: array:3 [
    0 => {#272
      +"id": 1
      +"doctor_id": "EZD0004"
      +"day": "13/Jun/2018"
      +"time_slot": "10:00PM,11:00PM,12:00PM"
      +"status": "Available"
}
1 => {#270
      +"id": 3
      +"doctor_id": "EZD0004"
      +"day": "24/Jun/2018"
      +"time_slot": "12:00pm,1:00pm"
      +"status": "admitted"
}
]
}
```

What should I change to get my desired output?

This is in laravel framework.
Thanks.

Comment: most likely your query isn't right

Comment: Show what is the output of `$lists`: `echo '<pre>' . print_r($lists, true) . '</pre>';`

Comment: Use `dd($lists)` to see what it contains

Comment: query is correct if statement works only when i provide the else it doesn't get the desired output@Akintunde Olawale.I have updated with dd @kerbholz

Comment: The problem is maybe with `$api_procedure['Day']>$today`, `$today` is a date but `$api_procedure['Day']` is a string, no?

Comment: You might need to work with [Carbon dates](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) to compare them. Make `$today` and `$api_procedure['Day']` a Carbon date, compare them and see if that works

Comment: yes $api_procedure['Day'] is a string.You guys are correct i think,if might not be working because of that.Let me check with carbon.

Comment: I converted then still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$inputs = \Input::all();
$lists =  Gateway::Onlineschedule()->schedulelist($inputs['doctor_id']);
$today = Carbon::today()->format('d/M/Y');

$new_records = [];
        foreach ($lists as $list) 
        {
            $api_procedure['Day'] = $list->day; 
            $api_procedure['Day'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/M/Y', $api_procedure['Day'])->format('d/M/Y');

            if($api_procedure['Day'] > $today)
            {
                $new_records[] = $api_procedure;
            }

        }

        if(count($new_records) > 0) 
        {
             return $new_records;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return 'No records';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you first convert both dates to a timestamp. Write your if else statement this way:

```
$api_procedure['Day'] = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($list->day))); 

$today = strtotime('now');

if ($api_procedure['Day'] > $today) {
    $listing[] = $api_procedure;
} else {
    return 'No dates available';
}
```

Comment: Its not working.It shows 'No dates available' even if $api_procedure['Day'] > $today condition holds true.I really don't understand this where i am getting this wrong.Ealier i used laravel carbon to convert the dates ,thenalso no luck.

Comment: @gaan10 what do you get when you print out $api_procedure['Day'] and $today individually?

Comment: @gaan10 glad to know you were able to resolve the bottleneck